# Flutter external libs - Specify a namespace error

Tags: flutter, dart, gradle, namespaces, libraries

I have error with external libs for my flutter project. When I run my project as a debug  version everything is working okay, but when I run my project as a release version then I have issue like below. I tried to change compileSdk version, but it's not helped. I tried to change buildType, but still not working. Problem is with 2 libraries:

```
  android_package_manager: ^0.6.0
  flutter_logs: ^2.1.11
```

App gradle:

```
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '7'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '2.7.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

android {
    namespace "com.roundbyte.dmsrcp.dms_rcp"
    compileSdkVersion flutter.compileSdkVersion
    ndkVersion "25.1.8937393"

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_17
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_17
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '17'
    }

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.roundbyte.dmsrcp.dms_rcp"
        // You can update the following values to match your application needs.
        // For more information, see: https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android#reviewing-the-gradle-build-configuration.
        minSdkVersion flutter.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion flutter.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
            shrinkResources false
            minifyEnabled false
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
}
```

Project Gradle:

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.9.10'
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.2.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

tasks.register("clean", Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Error:

```
FAILURE: Build completed with 2 failures.

1: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':android_package_manager'.
> Could not create an instance of type com.android.build.api.variant.impl.LibraryVariantBuilderImpl.
   > Namespace not specified. Specify a namespace in the module's build file. See https://d.android.com/r/tools/upgrade-assistant/set-namespace for information about setting the namespace.

     If you've specified the package attribute in the source AndroidManifest.xml, you can use the AGP Upgrade Assistant to migrate to the namespace value in the build file. Refer to https://d.android.com/r/tools/upgrade-assistant/agp-upgrade-assistant for general information about using the AGP Upgrade Assistant.

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.
==============================================================================

2: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
Failed to query the value of property 'buildFlowServiceProperty'.
> Could not isolate value org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.plugin.statistics.BuildFlowService$Parameters_Decorated@34b86c9c of type BuildFlowService.Parameters
   > A problem occurred configuring project ':android_package_manager'.
      > Could not create an instance of type com.android.build.api.variant.impl.LibraryVariantBuilderImpl.
         > Namespace not specified. Specify a namespace in the module's build file. See https://d.android.com/r/tools/upgrade-assistant/set-namespace for information about setting the namespace.

           If you've specified the package attribute in the source AndroidManifest.xml, you can use the AGP Upgrade Assistant to migrate to the namespace value in the build file. Refer to https://d.android.com/r/tools/upgrade-assistant/agp-upgrade-assistant for general information about using the AGP Upgrade Assistant.

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.
==============================================================================

BUILD FAILED in 1s
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...                         2 307ms
Exception: Gradle task assembleRelease failed with exit code 1
#0      throwToolExit (package:flutter_tools/src/base/common.dart:10:3)
#1      AndroidGradleBuilder.buildGradleApp (package:flutter_tools/src/android/gradle.dart:491:9)
<asynchronous suspension>
#2      AndroidGradleBuilder.buildApk (package:flutter_tools/src/android/gradle.dart:220:5)
<asynchronous suspension>
#3      AndroidDevice.startApp (package:flutter_tools/src/android/android_device.dart:578:7)
<asynchronous suspension>
#4      FlutterDevice.runCold (package:flutter_tools/src/resident_runner.dart:533:33)
<asynchronous suspension>
#5      ColdRunner.run (package:flutter_tools/src/run_cold.dart:57:28)
<asynchronous suspension>
#6      RunCommand.runCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/commands/run.dart:745:27)
<asynchronous suspension>
#7      FlutterCommand.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command.dart:1350:27)
<asynchronous suspension>
#8      AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:150:19)
<asynchronous suspension>
#9      CommandRunner.runCommand (package:args/command_runner.dart:212:13)
<asynchronous suspension>
#10     FlutterCommandRunner.runCommand.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command_runner.dart:348:9)
<asynchronous suspension>
#11     AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:150:19)
<asynchronous suspension>
#12     FlutterCommandRunner.runCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command_runner.dart:294:5)
<asynchronous suspension>
#13     run.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/runner.dart:112:9)
<asynchronous suspension>
#14     AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:150:19)
<asynchronous suspension>
#15     main (package:flutter_tools/executable.dart:90:3)
<asynchronous suspension>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a problem with the `android_package_manager` package that you use. If you look at its [build.gradle](https://github.com/nsNeruno/android_package_manager/blob/cbc44a9fe1be342f185a103f3e564286476f8d91/android/build.gradle) file, you'll notice it's missing `namespace` which is required as of Android Gradle Plugin v8.

Alternatively you can downgrade to AGP v7 and Gradle v7, but I don't recommend doing that, unless for a brief moment (if you're in an emergency situation).

Comment: Thank you. I removed problematic libraries and changed logic to walk around the problem.